# Trying to use Eclipse WindowBuilder, but ActionLister isn't doing anything

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton, windowbuilder

I've tried checking out about 5 different tutorials for WindowBuilder, and while I can get an application window to appear when I test the code, I cannot get the buttons to work. This is the code I've made based on the tutorials I've seen.

```
package guiTest;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GuiTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GuiTest window = new GuiTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public GuiTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JButton btnLabelAdd = new JButton("Label Add");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnLabelAdd = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnLabelAdd.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_btnLabelAdd.gridx = 6;
        gbc_btnLabelAdd.gridy = 1;
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLabelAdd, gbc_btnLabelAdd);
        btnLabelAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                makeLabel(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeLabel(ActionEvent evt) {
        JLabel lblHereLabel = new JLabel("Here Label");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblHereLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblHereLabel.gridx = 6;
        gbc_lblHereLabel.gridy = 4;
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblHereLabel, gbc_lblHereLabel);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any tips to get this to work? Or some example code I could use to make sure the problem is not with Eclipse? I'm assuming here that the button should make the label when the button is left clicked; is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your button works fine.  You can watch the code jump into `makeLabel()` in a debugger.  You just aren't making the new label visible.

As suggested by @MadProgrammer, once you've added the new label, you can tell the enclosing `Container` to update itself by calling `revalidate()`, and then `repaint()` to have it redraw itself:

```
private void makeLabel(ActionEvent evt) {
    JLabel lblHereLabel = new JLabel("Here Label");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblHereLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblHereLabel.gridx = 6;
    gbc_lblHereLabel.gridy = 4;
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblHereLabel, gbc_lblHereLabel);
    frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
}
```

Doing this means that you've divorced yourself from needing to access `frame` directly.  This means that you can rewrite your handler to be "frame agnostic", by querying the button that fired the event for the `Container` it belongs to, and just add the new label to it, like so:

```
private void makeLabel(ActionEvent evt) {
    JLabel lblHereLabel = new JLabel("Here Label");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblHereLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblHereLabel.gridx = 6;
    gbc_lblHereLabel.gridy = 4;

    Container displayArea = ((JButton) evt.getSource()).getParent();
    displayArea.add(lblHereLabel, gbc_lblHereLabel);
    displayArea.revalidate();
    displayArea.repaint();
}
```

Comment: You could also just use `revalidate` and `repaint` instead of `frame.setVisible` to force a layout and paint pass - which I would consider "better practice" as you really should decouple your code from knowing anything about the frame ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks!  Updated.

Comment: Thanks so much you two! Finally got it to work, now I can get actually get started with implementing a GUI for my program.

Comment: I disagree with @MadProgrammer & azurefrog as to the best path to a solution. I'd add a blank (no text, visible border or icon) label at start-up. Such a label is invisible & cannot get the input focus, so the user won't know it is there.  On button action, set the text or icon to **make it** 'visible' automatically, without worrying about the immediate parent ***or*** top level container.